# HTML e CSS: Componente Personalizado

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Encontrei o componente abaixo num site e gostaria de aprender a fazê-lo.
Alguém sabe de algum tutorial que o ensine?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando passa o mouse sobre ele fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vi esse componente no site da [Organizze](https://www.organizze.com.br/) na parte de Lançamentos.

Comment: Existe várias formas de fazer isso. Poderia mostrar o site que você retirou?

Comment: Editei a questão Randrade. Não precisa cadastrar lá, só entrar com o facebook mesmo.

Comment: @Raphael, da uma olhada [Bootstrap Dropdowns](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp)

Comment: Valeu @David, mas não é muito bem isso. Esse componente é uma espécie de slide (naquelas setinhas) com um combobox (que só abre as opções com o evento hover).

Comment: Então você precisa de dois tutoriais, um de [dropdown hover](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp) e outro de [slideshow](https://www.sitepoint.com/make-a-simple-javascript-slideshow-without-jquery/).